# UIView "stuck" in UITabBarController view top left corner

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, positioning

I'm initializing a loader subview to match the height, width and position of the UITabBar I'm using to wrap my app:

```
// In UITabBarController implementation

LoaderView *loaderView = [[LoaderView alloc] initWithFrame:[self tabBar].viewForBaselineLayout.frame];
[[self view] addSubview:loaderView];

//
//  LoaderView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoaderView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *messageLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *message;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect frame;

- (void)createLabel;
- (void)drawLoader;
- (void)setText:(NSString *)newMessage;
- (void)show:(NSNotification *)notification;

@end

//
//  LoaderView.m

#import "LoaderView.h"

@implementation LoaderView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self drawLoader];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawLoader
{
    UIColor *semiOpaqueGray = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.8f];
    [self setBackgroundColor:semiOpaqueGray];

    [self createLabel];
}

- (void)createLabel
{
    _messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(15,9,([self frame].size.width - 10), 30)];
    _messageLabel.textColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1];
    _messageLabel.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0];

    [self addSubview:_messageLabel];
}

@end
```

The `frame` struct represents this incoming frame data:

```
2013-09-16 07:48:35.552 ---[97825:a0b] {{0, 519}, {320, 49}}
// Ostensibly 0,519 origin point and 320,49 w/h
```

The result is this. The mostly opaque dark box can be spotted in the top left corner. It looks like it's being positioned by its center point of the loader to the top left most point of the screen:

[image: Screenshot of misplaced gray box]

I can make the size of the box change, but I can't seem to move it from that top left position. Further, I set an animation on it, and that animation adjusts the frame (sliding it up an down from the tab bar area). That seems to have no effect either.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what class is your superview? this: [[self view] addSubview:loaderView];

Answer (score 1):

You can gently add your loadingView your application window. After set the frame of loaderView.

```
[loadView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width.,self.frame.size.height)];
[self.window addSubview:loaderView];
```

Then after loading finished.

```
[self.window removeSubview:loaderView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your superview is the problem. If you're adding it to your UINavigationController then the y-axis likely won't respond nicely. Try using the primary view of your controller

```
loaderView.frame = CGRectMake(x, 514, 40, 320);  // made up numbers
[self.mapView addSubview:loaderView];
```

Also you're accessing your tabBar. Try using UIDevice window for getting your width and inherit the height from your labels on the bottom (or nest the labels within your LoaderView)

Also look into actually using UITabBar for handling this.

Comment: Your example doesn't show any result whatsoever. I did try adding the view to the UITabBar view and it had the result of moving said graphic so that its center point was oriented to the top left corner of the tab bar, but again, just as stuck.

Comment: First try setting the backgroundColor for your tabbar. I already picked up your color for you, here's the code: tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(46.0/255.0) green:(45.0/255.0) blue:(46.0/255.0) alpha:1.0f];

Comment: also, if you're using center you need to import QuartzCore into your file header, try adding this: #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>, also make sure you add it to your Target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries

Comment: Yeah, these things didn't help either. What it ended up taking was adding the loader to the self.tabBar, then pushing it behind it. Solution forthcoming.